# Pro Tem Moderators Announcement (at last!)

Tags: discussion

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that every community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Nero]
[image: trichoplax]
[image: Dan Hulme]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them and appreciate the hard work and time they will contribute.

**Update:**
We're pleased to share that Dan Hulme has recently joined the pro-tem moderation team in place of Martin Ender. Martin, thanks for all your hard work!

[image: Martin Ender]

#### Did we overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are many members here who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. Our failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, moderators should be elected by the community, and that's why we'll hold elections once the site graduates.

Most of all, it's important to be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Ty, and we now have got mathjax too.